# Is it possible to bleach Sapele wood?

Tags: wood

Can I bleach [Sapele](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapele) wood? I want it much lighter & less red. I have tried rubbing down with coarse wire wool & applying lime wax unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

Try using oxalic acid - you may be able to buy it at the local hardware store as "wood bleach"; it comes in crystal form to be mixed with water.

Pity, though, to take that marvelous color out of sapele! Good thing you didn't buy bloodwood (muninga) or redheart... 8)

Comment: Note too that sunlight will gradually bleach most woods.